# How come the div cannot display in the center?

Tags: css

I tried the following code :

```
#my_div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:700px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/kwcSc/)

As far as I know is that margin-left and margin-right set to auto will center the div. But how come it doesn't work like that?

Thanks.

Comment: It works exactly like that.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle.net example to demonstrate this? Your css is correct.

Comment: Hmm but I tried it on JSFiddle, the content is always on the left side?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kwcSc/

Comment: What browser and version are you using? Im using chrome and your jsfiddle is working just fine

Comment: I am using Chrome. Version 24.0.1312.56 m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does, you just have to make sure your window is more than 700px wide. Here is a working example with 200px width:

```
#my_div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaygee79/8QEkE/)

Comment: Oh man, I need to make the screen larger :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a specificity issue. Try adding !important to your declarations:

```
#my_div {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    width:700px;
    background-color:red;
}
```